# Getting permutations in Python, itertools

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I want to get all the 3 letter permutations possible from every letter in the alphabet using itertools. This comes back blank:

```
import itertools 

def permutations(ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ, r=3):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    for indices in product(range(n), repeat=r):
        if len(set(indices)) == r:
            yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `iterable` defined? Please include syntactically valid code

Comment: I'm just trying to learn from the docs, http://docs.python.org/library/itertools that's what it says.

Comment: That's not what it says you have changed it. Also that is just code explaining what `permutations` does

Comment: `iterable` is a variable name. It doesn't mean anything unless you assign a value to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code in the `itertools.permutations` documentation explains how the function is implemented, not how to use it. You want to do this:

```
perms = itertools.permutations('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', r=3)
```

You can print them all out by converting it to a list (`print(list(perms))`), but you can just iterate over them in a `for` loop if you want to do something else with them - eg,

```
for perm in perms:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I iterate through them will it be using ABC or (A,B,C)?

Comment: @lvc I have a very huge list from a cssv to find permutation from having r = 6, and I get the lack of memory error. How do you suggest I overcome this?

Answer (score 10):

You are a bit mixed up, that is just code explaining what `permutations` does. `itertools` is actually written in C code, the python **equivalent** is just given to show how it works.

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> from string import ascii_uppercase
>>> for x in permutations(ascii_uppercase, r=3):
        print x


('A', 'B', 'C')    
('A', 'B', 'D')
('A', 'B', 'E')    
('A', 'B', 'F')
.....
```

That should work fine